# isKindOfClass returning different values for Test Cases

Tags: ios, iphone, unit-testing, xctest, xctestexpectation

I have a method `someMethod`. This method, at some point has the following if-else condition.

```
- (void) someMethod {
    // ... some more code ... 
    if ([userArray[0] isKindOfClass:[Me class]]) {
        // some code
    }
    else {
        // some other code
    }
}
```

Now this if-condition is always met when I execute the code normally. But when I call it from one of my test-cases, the else-part gets executed instead. I am calling this method exactly the same way (it has no side-effects, etc).

When I debugged the thing in both normal run, and testing run. I saw something different.

While running in Test, the userArray had 1 object, `(Me_Me_2 *)0x00007fa61d39dbf0`.
And while running it normally, the userArray had the same object, but there was one difference. It said `(Me_Me_ *)0x00007fce71459ae0`.

When I print the value of `NSStringFromClass([userArray[0] class])`, they both print "Me".

"Me" is a NSManagedObject.

Another interesting thing is, if I add an expression in the debugger and evaluate it, it always evaluates to true - `([((NSObject*)userArray[0]) isKindOfClass:[Me class]])` returns `(bool)true`. This is totally bizarre! If the condition is true, why does it ever go into the else block?

Now some questions -

1. What is happening over here? Are Core Data objects treated different when running in tests?
2. Why is the type of the object "Me_Me_2" while testing and "Me_Me_" otherwise? Why is it not just "Me"?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds similar to the following issue: [isKindOfClass doesn't work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386189/iskindofclass-doesnt-work-as-expected)

In short, is the class being compared a target member of the test target? It should only be a target member of the application.